# Update data source for D3 TopoJSON map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, topojson

I am currently attempting to update the data source for a TopoJson map so that the points on the map get replotted when a button is pressed / updateData() function is called.

Here is my code:

```
<head>

<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

<style>
path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
  fill: grey;
}


</style>

    </head>

<body>


    <div id="option">
<input name="updateButton" 
             type="button" 
            value="Update" 
            onclick="updateData()" />
```

```
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

   var projection = d3.geo.mercator()

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the World
d3.json("data/world-110m2.json", function(error, topology) {

// load and display the cities
d3.json("data/commodities3.json", function(error, data) {
    g.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.location_lon, d.location_lat])[0];})
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.location_lon, d.location_lat])[1];})
       .style("fill", function(d){
    if(d.commodity_text == "Tin") {
    return "blue";
  } else {
    return "red";
  }


})
       .attr("r", function(d){
    if(d.commodity_text == "Iron") {
    return 10;
  } else {
    return 4;
  }


});
});




g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});

// zoom and pan
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        g.selectAll("path")  
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 

  });

svg.call(zoom)

function updateData(){

     var g = svg.append("g").transition();

     d3.json("data/commodities3.json", function(error, data) {
    g.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return projection([d.location_lon, d.location_lat])[0];})
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return projection([d.location_lon, d.location_lat])[1];})
       .style("fill", function(d){
    if(d.commodity_text == "Tin") {
    return "blue";
  } else {
    return "red";
  }


})
       .attr("r", function(d){
    if(d.commodity_text == "Iron") {
    return 10;
  } else {
    return 4;
  }


});
});




}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I am calling my transition function on my variable 'g', but I am not sure where to progress from here. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The only difference to your initial code is that you need to handle the update and exit selections as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am attempting to follow this tutorial: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html But I am not sure what to call to update?

Comment: [This tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) should help.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the link. I have created this:http://jsfiddle.net/2D3sB/ However, nothing happens when I click my update button. I would be very grateful if you could give me any advice? Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work -- you need to put the data somewhere as well.

Comment: Don't worry, I managed to get it working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer for reference?